# Extracting array from Ruby Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following Hash -

`{ result: [ {id: 378, name: 'Pete'}, {id: 567, name: 'Pete'} ] }`

I want to extract array of id's from this hash, something like this -

`[378, 567]`

Whats the shortest way to do it, apart from looping through the result array. Theres a map method for this but I am not quite sure how to use it.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

That [`map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map) method is pretty convenient. If your input looks like this:

```
input = { :result => [ {:id => 378, :name => 'Pete'}, {:id => 567, :name => 'Pete'} ] }
```

You can extract the `ids` like so:

```
ids = input[:result].map{ |obj| obj[:id] }

puts ids.inspect
```

[Check it out](http://codepad.org/WCHqAaI4).

Comment: For some `collect` method feels more intuitive.. ; )

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use map in order to get those values. You can use the following technique:

```
    a = { result: [ {id: 378, name: 'Pete'}, {id: 567, name: 'Pete'} ] }
    i= [0,1]
    output_value  = []
    for b in i 
            output_value  << a.values[0][b][:id]
    end 

    output_value
```